# Establish the proper prediction threshold

Tags: deep-learning, prediction, threshold

Suppose for a ML classification problem X, I have three labels, i.e. 1, 0 and -1. For some reasons, I obtained bad accuracy. So I decided to change the number of labels to two, i.e. 1 and -1. That way I got much better result. Now, when I am in the prediction phase, I want first to find what is my threshold level for precision/recall. If the prediction is not within those levels, assume 0. Programmatically, what is the proper way to establish that threshold?

Answer (score 2):

Do not use [classification thresholds](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312119/1352) unless you understand the trade-offs of your *decision*.

Do not use accuracy to evaluate a classifier: [Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352)

(See [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5004/1352) for a general motivation for this answer. See [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) for a motivation for short answers. Longer answers are always welcome.)